# How to change .htaccess deny action to "abort"

Tags: apache, .htaccess, rules

I have implemented various deny rules in my Apache .htaccess file.  The default deny action is a 403 (forbidden) response from my web server.  Is there a way to change Apache's deny action to "abort" (no response) analogous to IIS 8+ denyAction="AbortRequest"?  Ideally, I would like to be able to specify this "abort" action in the .htaccess file.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can't literally "abort" the request (as in "drop" the connection and send no response) in `.htaccess`.

> The default deny action is a 403

That's what the (Apache 2.2) `deny` directive does. You can override this HTTP response status using a custom `ErrorDocument 403` (requires another server-side script) or use a mod_rewrite (or mod_alias) directive to send a different response (a different method entirely), but in all cases you are still sending an HTTP response.